# Clearing Session in Global Application_Error

Tags: .net, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

Whenever an unhandled exception occurs on our site, I want to:

- Send a notification email
- Clear the user's session
- Send the user to a error page ("Sorry, a problem occurred...")

The first and last I've had working for a long time but the second is causing me some issues.  My Global.asax.vb includes:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Send exception report
    Dim ex As System.Exception = Nothing
    If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Server IsNot Nothing Then
        ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError
    End If
    Dim eh As New ErrorHandling(ex)
    eh.SendError()

    ' Clear session
    If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Session IsNot Nothing Then
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear()
    End If

    ' User will now be sent to the 500 error page (by the CustomError setting in web.config)
End Sub
```

When I run a debug, I can see the session being cleared, but then on the next page the session is back again!

I eventually found a reference that suggests that changes to session will not be saved unless Server.ClearError is called.  Unfortunately, if I add this (just below the line that sets "ex") then the CustomErrors redirect doesn't seem to kick in and I'm left with a blank page?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: As a sub-question, is there a way to get vb.net code to look good on Stack Overflow or am I out of luck?

Comment: Have you tried using Session.Abandon() instead of Session.Clear() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clear the session on your custom error page?

Also, you might want to look into using ELMAH. It makes all the stuff you are trying to do easy and awesome.

Comment: Thanks.  I still have a slight issue with this approach in that it feels wrong to have the error page do cleanup but it certainly works.  It also easily solves another issue I'd not considered until now where 404 errors count as Application Errors but I certainly don't want those to clear the session!

Comment: Yeah, it's a little wacky. My error page even logs my error to the DB, which seems pretty silly, but it works, and I have more important things to do than be academically perfect all the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Brunis - In answer to your question (I had the same problem) your application may have crashed out to application_error at a point *before* you have access to the session information, such as Begin_Request stage.